# How can I compare a Property to a (boolean) literal in an Apache Camel route in Spring XML?

Tags: spring, routes, properties, javabeans

I am trying to get a Camel route to perform an action based on a conditional statement; if that condition is true, then it will execute the action. However, if that condition is false, then the action will not be executed.

The conditional statement is based on the value of a property that is being pulled from a ".properties" file. I have defined a `placeholderPrefix` and `placeholderSuffix` for the properties within a bean which are `{{` and `}}` respectively. In case it helps, that definition looks as follows:

```
<bean id="com.example.springPropertyConfigurer"
    class="com.example.PropertiesSpringPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg index="0"
        type="com.example.PropertiesInterface"
        ref="com.example.Properties" />
    <property name="placeholderPrefix" value="{{" />
    <property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}}" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

The snippet of code I currently have looks like this:

```
<camel:choice>
    <camel:when>
        <camel:simple>{{com.example.PropertyKey}} == 'true'</camel:simple>
            <camel:to uri="executingTargetAction" />
    </camel:when>
    <camel:otherwise>
        <!-- Empty block so that nothing happens -->
    </camel:otherwise>
</camel:choice>
```

As of right now, this method does not give me the desired outcome.

I have tried using both `<xpath>` and `<spel>` instead of `<simple>` to see if they work, but it seems like these expression languages all expect the left-hand side of the condition to contain an `Exchange` object from a Camel route. I do not want to compare anything to an Exchange object -- I only want to compare the property from the properties file to the given literal that I provide (which, in this case, is the boolean value 'true').

I am open to using any Camel expression languages besides `<simple>` and the others listed above that will perform this task.

Comment: The Camel version is 2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

you can use bean method inside choice & inside when. The return type of that method will be boolean so if returns true then your code inside when will be executed else not.

```
<choice>
<when>
<method ref="ABC" method="pqr" />
-----your desired logic-----
</when>
</choice>
```